How to use Azure OpenAI SDK with Whisper for speech-to-text translation
Using:
<PackageReference Include="Azure.AI.OpenAI" Version="2.0.0-beta.2" />

I have this simple code:
var client = new OpenAIClient(
    new ApiKeyCredential(apiKey),
    new OpenAIClientOptions { Endpoint = new Uri(apiEndPoint) }
    );

var transcriptionOptions = new AudioTranscriptionOptions() { ResponseFormat = AudioTranscriptionFormat.Simple };

var audioClient = client.GetAudioClient(deploymentId);
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);

var result = await audioClient.TranscribeAudioAsync(stream, fileName, transcriptionOptions);

I get a 404 error.
The endpoint and API key are taken directly from the playground quickstart window, so should be fine:

What am I missing?

Got it - just a matter of using the right types/classes:
var client = new AzureOpenAIClient(
    new Uri(apiEndPoint),
    new ApiKeyCredential(apiKey)
    );

var audioClient = client.GetAudioClient(deploymentId);
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);

var transcriptionOptions = new AudioTranscriptionOptions() { ResponseFormat = AudioTranscriptionFormat.Simple };
var result = await audioClient.TranscribeAudioAsync(stream, fileName, transcriptionOptions);

